# Chat App using GCM, PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging, android-volley, slim

I am following this tutorial

[Part-1](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-1)

[Part -2](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-2/)

part-1 has been done sucessfully and but in part -2 when i deploy app im my mobile then i am not getting any  **gcm registration token** in toast and neither in logcat.
As i have searched that due to my config.php file i am using ip s=address instead of hostname i had to change my link **from this**
http://live_host_ip_address/gcm_chat/v1/user/login ---->
 **to this**
http://live_host_ip_address/gcm_chat/v1/index.php/user/login

on using  **Postman Chrome REST API** with this link-http://live_host_ip_address/gcm_chat/v1/user/login  it was not working but on changing the link to http://live_host_ip_address/gcm_chat/v1/index.php/user/login the link begaun to work properly.

**On testing its showing volley error:null**

[image]

**and in Logcat its showing**

```
23676-24548/info.androidhive.gcm E/LoginActivity﹕ params: {email=example@gmail.com, name=abc}
 23676-24548/info.androidhive.gcm E/LoginActivity﹕ params: {email=example@gmail.com, name=abc}
 23676-23676/info.androidhive.gcm E/LoginActivity﹕ Volley error: null, code: null
 23676-23676/info.androidhive.gcm D/Volley﹕ [1] Request.finish: 7764 ms: [ ] http://live_ip_address/gcm_chat/v1/user/login 0x44e0acb1 NORMAL 7
```

**I think the problem lies in that i am using http://live_host_ip_address/gcm_chat/v1/index.php/user/login from the Postman Chrome REST API but in logcat its showing http://live_host_ip_address/gcm_chat/v1/user/login**

Comment: do you have `.htaccess` file inside your slim root directory ? If yes, then is urlrewriting is ON in your server??

Answer (score 2):

GCM is now deprecated, try to migrate using Firebase Cloud Messaging, 
Follow these tutorial series :

- [Send FCM using php part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LiKCEa5_Cs8)
- [Send FCM using php part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYZVhs6T_W8)

And this is an example to create simple chat app :

- [Chat App with Firebase Realtime Database part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wVCz1a3ogqk)
- [Chat App with Firebase Realtime Database part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uX6_w6yhj4E)

Comment: ok will see to it also but for now do you have any clue regarding my above problem...it will be great help ?

Comment: I think  not getting registration token is the main issue here.. So did you use correct SHA1?

Comment: where to use SHA1 i have used google-services.json in the android project and API Key in the php config file ?

Comment: GCM is NOT deprecated, it is still fully supported and you can continue to use it. FCM is now the recommended way to send messages but GCM implementations will continue to work and are supported.

Comment: hi @AndroidPutra did you find any answer to that I am facing the same problem

Comment: No friend @FaisalNaseer please up-vote this question so that it could be answered or sloved

Comment: @AndroidPutra yesterday it was giving particular error but now its running smooth as it wasnot getting GCM id that time and afterwards when I ran for the second time it worked well.